How can I measure or estimate the forces on the members in this pic, given a specific force on a specific member?
sorry in advance for how dumb I am. Trying to figure out how to build a thing (slide-in camper) so it's ridiculously light weight yet still big and roomy.
Just starting to learn CAD (FreeCAD), and have the beginnings of a model of what the camper will eventually look like:

Missing pieces (so far): 1) front and rear walls, 2) ceiling, 3) jack stands, mounted on some kind of strong beam at the four corners, 4) a cab-over section that starts at the middle of the rear wall and extends out about 1/4 the current length.
So basically it will look mostly like:
.
I am vaguely aware of the forces that will interact with the structure, like shear, bending, compression, tension, etc. But at the moment my major concern is tension and compression at the lower joints/angles, due to the materials I'm using and the weight of the whole structure when loaded.
The main material used is extruded polystyrene (XPS) foam attached together with polyurethane adhesive (Gorilla Glue) using finger joints, which isn't very strong (25psi compression, 50psi flexural, 2% maximum change... basically it has very weak edge strength and weak tensile strength). The foam structure is plenty strong to support itself, but start adding a lot of heavy stuff inside it and suddenly all those right angles of just foam look pretty sus.
If I wrapped this in a lot of fiberglass, it would have plenty of strength & rigidity (basically it'd be an upside-down boat). But as a curiosity (& because I love doing everything the hard way) I'd like to know exactly what members of this structure will be loaded (for example by the weight of a heavy floor) and how to calculate which of the members here need to be strengthened in such a way as to resist structural failure.
For example: say there is a heavy weight applied on the floor from inside the camper (say, 1200lbs), and the camper is sitting on its jack stands on the four corners. First, the jack stands must be strong enough to support the weight; they must be attached to beams on the corners which can withstand the weight; and (I assume) the rest of the structure must be able to support itself in this position.
For that last bit (the structure has to stay intact with all that weight on the floor while it's jacked up), it would seem at first that all those 90-degree angles of only foam aren't remotely strong enough to hold 1200lbs! But the front and rear walls will be attached to the edges, so when the floor is loaded down, the floor is pulling down on the walls in tension, and those 90-degree angles are now also using the walls to help support the load in tension. (I could be totally wrong about this, i'm just guessing!)
If this is correct, then, for example, how can I tell how strong the walls would need to be in tension to support this load? How can I tell how much those 90-degree angles would also need to be strengthened? And (sorry, too many questions) would anyone have a suggestion for how to strengthen those 90-degree corners? (I'm guessing fiberglass tape, or maybe gluing in some aluminum angles?)
(As an aside: I plan on wrapping the whole thing with canvas impregnated with waterproof PVA glue, mostly for waterproofing & durability, but I'm assuming it would also provide a small amount of tensile strength to the structure)
Sorry again for the weird questions, and thanks in advance!

There are too many questions at once, could you maybe split this into multiple standalone questions? You would greatly increase the chance of getting relevant answers.
Regarding the structure, I think a beam structure is much better than panels. Maybe you could combine the two.
